# Calculating the energy required to observe Bragg reflection

Tags: braggs-law

The distance between crystals plane is approximately $10^{-10}m$ what approximate photon energy is required to observe Bragg reflection from the planes. Can someone explain how the answer was calculated.

The answer is $4*10^{3}eV$ (electron volts).

Can someone please give a good detailed answer, i thought i was genius at Bragg's law until i came across this.

Comment: Presumably you know the relationship between energy and wavelength. What wavelength do you need to get Bragg reflection? Is it an upper or a lower limit?

Comment: Energy=(Plank's Constant)*(Speed of light)/(Wavelength). I'm not sure what wavelength you need to get Bragg reflection

Comment: Do you have a reference to "the answer" - given that my calculation seems to disagree it would be good to dig a little deeper into the source of your information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach - which doesn't quite give the same answer you were looking for...

From [Bragg's Law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/bragg.html), we know

$$n\lambda = 2d\sin\theta$$

This tells us that the smaller the angle $\theta$, the shorter the wavelength - and the shorter the wavelength, the greater the energy, since wavelength and energy are related through the relationship:

$$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

The maximum allowed wavelength (lowest energy) is the one for which $n=1$ and $\theta = 90°$. Then $\lambda = 2d$.

The rest is substitution of numbers in the above equations. A handy shortcut is given on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_energy):

$$E = \frac{1.2398}{\lambda (µm)} ~\rm{eV}$$

with the wavelength given in µm. Given $\lambda = 2d = 2\times10^{-10}$ m, the above evaluates to

$$E = \frac{1.24}{2\times 10^{-4}~µm} = 6.2 ~\rm{keV}$$

Not sure why that is not exactly the same as the answer you were given. There seems to be about a $\sqrt{2}$ difference...